# proxy does not interecept object

Tags: javascript

I have this following problem here:

I try to create a mini framework for learning / experimenting purposes. I have this markup

```
 <button click="cool">click me</button>
```

This is my custom attribute to bind event handlers. I collect them like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[click]").forEach(listener => {
  let name = listener.attributes.click.nodeValue;
  listener.addEventListener(
    "click",
    this.staticProp[name].bind(this.staticProp)
  );
});
```

Everything happens inside an class. I pass my properties that i want to make reactive like this:

```
new Tinyflow({
  prog: "programm",
  howDoesItWork: "good",
  age: 21,
  cool() {
    console.log("nice");
    console.log(this.age);
    this.age++;
  }
});

  constructor(properties) {
    this.reactivityHandler = {
      set(vars, prop, newVal) {
        console.log("i work");
      },
      get(data, prop, newVal) {
        console.log("i work");
      }
    };
    this.staticProp = properties;
    this.passedProps = new Proxy(this.staticProp, this.reactivityHandler);
  }
```

I expect that the `reactivityHandler` gets triggered whenever my props changes, but nothing happens. In my console i see `nice` and how `age` increases but i dont see `i work`.

Why doesnt the proxy intercept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `this.passedProps` to the `Proxy`, while you access the properties directly with `this.age`. If you want it to go through the proxy, then access the properties through `this.passedProps.age` and `this.passedProps.age++`.

Comment: thank you, i changed `.bind(this.staticProp)` to `.bind(this.passedProps)` and the proxy intercepts whenever i increase age like this `this.age++`